# Java return type is an Object. Complains about initialization. Best approach with use of try and catch

Tags: java, methods

I have this public method within a class

```
public Flight getFlight(int flightNumber){
    Flight flightFound;
    try{
        for (int i=0; i<fl.length; i++){            
            if(fl[i].getFlightNumber()==flightNumber){
                flightFound= fl[i];
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("The object does not exist"); 
    } finally{
        return flightFound;
    }
}
```

The purpose of method within a learning exercise, is to return the corresponding object with the flight number passed in to the method. What would be good error checking like try catch blocks?
Also the current method complains that return flightFound may not be initialized.

So my question would be what are some good practices with returning the object, and error checking if the object is not present?

```
public class Manager {
    Flight[] fl;
    Ticket[] ticket;

    public void createFlights(){
        this.fl = new Flight[5];
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
            fl[i]= new Flight();
        }

        this.fl[0].Flight(1030, "Toronto", "Kolkata", "03/02/14 7:50 pm", 250, 1450.00);
        this.fl[1].Flight(1040, "Toronto", "Lahore", "03/02/14 7:10 pm", 250, 1450.00);
        this.fl[2].Flight(1050, "Toronto", "Kolkata", "03/02/14 1:50 pm", 250, 1450.00);
        this.fl[3].Flight(1060, "Toronto", "Lahore", "03/02/14 1:10 pm", 250, 1450.00);
        this.fl[4].Flight(1070, "New York", "Kolkata", "03/02/14 4:50 pm", 250, 1450.00);
    }

    public void displayAvailableFlights(String origin, String destination){
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
             if ((this.fl[i].getOrigin().equals(origin)) &&(this.fl[i].getDestination().equals(destination))){
                if (this.fl[i].getNumberOfSeatsLeft()>0){
                    System.out.println(this.fl[i].toString());
                }
             }
        }
    }

    public Flight getFlight(int flightNumber){
        Flight flightFound = new Flight();
        try{
            for (int i=0; i<fl.length; i++){

                if(fl[i].getFlightNumber()==flightNumber){
                    flightFound= fl[i];
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
               System.out.println("The object does not exist"); 
        } 
        finally{
            return flightFound;
        }
   }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Manager man = new Manager();
        Flight flightFound = new Flight();
        man.createFlights();
        man.displayAvailableFlights("Toronto", "Kolkata");
        flightFound=man.getFlight(030);
        System.out.println(flightFound.toString());
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there a possibility that `fl[i]` is null?

Comment: First of all, which method can throw an exception in your try block? is any of the `Flight`s in the array `fl` null? If so, you should check for null value instead of letting the code throw (so you won't need the try/catch at all). Then you should decide what to do if the flight number is not found: return null or throw an exception are options. Finally, you don't really need the `finally` block.

Comment: One more thing. Working with raw arrays is ok, but you will find that the [Java collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) are much more powerful and provide many ways to organize your objects.

Comment: Never **ever** return in a `finally` block. Also, use a `Map`.

Comment: Christian, technically there could be a null one. I have made it such that it will always return the correct one. But how should I handle the null case?

Comment: Giovanni, i dont have a particular method to throw the exception. I am new to this sort of stuff. And basically would like to know the best practice of handling a null case, where the flight is not in the array which i assume would be using the try catch blocks right?
Also I saw some code in another post and got the finally from that.

Answer (score 0):

There are two schenerios in which flightFound may not be initiallsed,so compiler insisting you to initialise it.

fl.length = 0

or

fl[i].getFlightNumber() != flightNumber in all array indexes

Answer (score 0):

Flight flightFound is local to getFlight(int flightNumber) method and you are initializing in 
try block, if an exception occurs(before if) in try block then control will be transferred to catch block and  flightFound may not be initialized. or if fl[i].getFlightNumber()==flightNumber is false then flightFound may not be initialized.